# Codenameone: Register iOS App as share target

Tags: codenameone

I found an [article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/associating-your-app-with-file-extension-mime-types-iphone-android-windows.html) where a solution is described how to register an codenamone app as a target for "open with" on an iOS device. Is there also a way to register an codenamone app as a share target on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy integration for that since the share functionality requires the creation of an extension and that would require some native code: 
[How to add my app to the share sheet action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497578/how-to-add-my-app-to-the-share-sheet-action)

This is something that's a bit hard to automate since you would need to implement logic that indicates whether a specific file is valid etc. It's something we could implement if there's demand for it but we didn't get around to doing it.