# Codenameone: Add an action extension on iOS

Tags: codenameone

As posted some months ago I would like to call my app on iOS from within the share sheet ([Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223994/codenameone-register-ios-app-as-share-target/56230593#56230593)). The answer was: It‘s possible with an action extension. I now built an action extension as xcode-projekt. My question is, how to integrate the code (incl. the info.plist) in my CN1 project so that the CN1-Build integrates it in the final build as action extension?

### #

EDIT: Screenshot added with the CN1-builded iOS-Source included in xcode and after adding an action extension.
[image]

Comment: I suggest sending a build with "include source" then integrating the action sheet natively into the xcode project tracking the steps you took e.g. "added X to plist etc.". Ideally do a diff on the directory to see what changed exactly. Then ask the question such as "how do I add/change..." within the project. If it's just adding a file you can put it in the native directory. If it's just changing the plist you can use the plist inject build hint. If there's more we can help.

Comment: I did the steps you describend and added a screenshot (original posting) of the file-structure after I added an action extension to the project. It seems, that only a new directory "Zeitkuenstler" (the name I inputed for the extension) is added under "dist" - with it's own info.plist file. So what could be the next step to integrate this extension in the CN1 build?

Comment: Does it work if you just place the files in the native/ios folder? Do you have a pro or higher subscription? If so please email support and we'll try and work with you on that directly.