# how make my app appear first in other apps's sharing dialog

Tags: android, ios, mobile

im developing a social media app, i want others to be able to easily share content to my app. What can I do to be able to being rank in front like Whatsapp and X in other apps' sharing dialog? or it is entirely decided by the owner of the app?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A4Rv.jpg)

not a expertise on this, i dont know what to try

Comment: As far as I know, it's decided by the OS system, based on the user's most recently used activity

Comment: no, this is in app sharing dialog, the one decided by the OS system is on the extreme right, this is the Youtube app btw

Comment: For iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497578/how-to-add-my-app-to-the-share-sheet-action.

Comment: It is up to the user to order their favourites using the "more..." dialog   There is nothing you can do in your app.